# how I can add the values using php and xpath with SUM() dom xml?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a table whose values ​​are loaded from an XML file, and need to add the price field values to get the total​​. I've been looking and seeing examples but I have not clear. How can I do add this precio fields?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Cervantes]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[El Quijote]]></titulo>
        <precio>30€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Calderón de la Barca]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[La vida es sueño]]></titulo>
        <precio>25€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Garcilaso de la vega]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[Egoglas]]></titulo>
        <precio>15€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Raymond Carver]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[Catedral]]></titulo>
        <precio>16€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[George Orwell]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[1984]]></titulo>
        <precio>10€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Fidor Dostoyevski]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[Crimen y Castigo]]></titulo>
        <precio>35€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Juan Ponce]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[Cronica de la intervencion]]></titulo>
        <precio>25€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Yukio Mishima]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[Confesiones de una mascara]]></titulo>
        <precio>22€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Elfriede Jelinek]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[Deseo]]></titulo>
        <precio>20€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Bram Stoker]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[Dracula]]></titulo>
        <precio>18€</precio>
    </libro>
</root>
```

PHP

```
<?         
   ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
   ini_set('display_errors','on'); 
           ob_start();
           $dom=new DOMDocument();
           $dom->load('xml/libros.xml');
           $libros=$dom->getElementsByTagName('libro');
           $i=0;
           echo "<table cellspacing='2'>";
           foreach ($libros as $libro) {
               $autores=$libro->getElementsByTagName('autor');
               $autor=$autores->item(0)->nodeValue;
               $titulos=$libro->getElementsByTagName('titulo');
               $titulo=$titulos->item(0)->nodeValue;
               $precios=$libro->getElementsByTagName('precio');
               $precio=$precios->item(0)->nodeValue;
               echo "<tr id='fila".$i."'>";
               echo "<td>".$autor."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$titulo."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$precio."</td>";
               echo "</tr>";
               $i++;
           }
           echo "</table>";
           $tabla=ob_get_contents();
           ob_end_clean();
           $console="Toda va ok";
           $aValores=array('tabla'=> $tabla,'console'=>$console);
           echo json_encode($aValores);  
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, the xpath should be `sum(//precio)`.
I couldn't get it to work, though. So I chose a less elegant, but functional approach:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
$sum = 0;
$h = "<table>";

foreach ($xml->libro as $book) {

    $h .= "<tr><td>".$book->autor."</td><td>".$book->titulo."</td><td>".$book->precio."</td></tr>";

    $sum += $book->precio;
}

$h .= "<tr><td colspan=\"2\">sum:</td><td>$sum</td></tr></table>";
echo $h;
```

I prefer `simplexml` over `dom`. If you look at my code, you'll understand why ;-)
Here's a life demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/q3drF5